# issue using r function with rpy2

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, rpy2

When I do

```
from rpy2.robjects import IntVector, Formula
from rpy2 import robjects
rr = Formula('gr_bmr~nationalite_france')
myparams = {'family': 'binomial'}     
formula=robjects.r('gr_bmr~nationalite_simple') 
robjects.r['glm'](rr,data=bdd1,**myparams)
```

I have this error: 
    Erreur dans eval(expr, envir, enclos) : les valeurs de y doivent être 0 <= y <= 1

```
RRuntimeError Traceback (most recent call last) in () ----> 1 robjects.r['glm'](rr,data=bdd1,**myparams)

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/functions.pyc in call(self, *args, **kwargs) 84 v = kwargs.pop(k) 85 kwargs[r_k] = v ---> 86 return super(SignatureTranslatedFunction, self).call(*args, **kwargs)

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/functions.pyc in call(self, *args, **kwargs) 33 for k, v in kwargs.iteritems(): 34 new_kwargs[k] = conversion.py2ri(v) ---> 35 res = super(Function, self).call(*new_args, **new_kwargs) 36 res = conversion.ri2py(res) 37 return res

RRuntimeError: Erreur dans eval(expr, envir, enclos) : les valeurs de y doivent être 0 <= y <= 1
```

I can translate in English if it is not clear. But, when I do the same thing in R, everything is working find:

```
glm(gr_bmr~nationalite_france,family=binomial,data=bdd1)

Call: glm(formula = gr_bmr ~ nationalite_france, family = binomial, data = bdd1)

Coefficients: (Intercept) nationalite_franceoui
-2.3609 -0.3604
```

How to solve it?

Comment: Unfortunately no message was left by whoever did the drive-by downvoting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solve it by replacing all boolean data ("oui,"non") by (1,0) in bdd1. As it is working without replacing in R, I think this is a bug from rpy2.
I don't understant why lgautier votes -1, this is not justified.

BR

Comment: I did not vote -1, and I commented that whoever voted -1 did not leave a message about why he/she did so.

Comment: If you think this is bug, it should be reported on the bug tracker for rpy2. However, I think that it has more to do with missing that in R a data.frame will (by default) transform a vector of strings to a `factor`, and that in your Python structure this is just a vector of strings.

Answer (score 0):

In you R code, `binomial` is a function while in your Python code it is a string. Try:

```
from rpy2.robjects import Formula
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
rr = Formula('gr_bmr~nationalite_france')
stats = importr('stats')
myparams = {'family': stats.binomial}
stats.glm(rr,data=bdd1,**myparams)
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply. I tried exactly what you said. I still the same message about the values of y. The values of y are "oui" or "non".